# Twig template - Loop iteration sum items in loop

Tags: symfony, templates, for-loop, twig, iteration

```
{% for product in products %}
     {% set totalPrice = (product.quantity * product.price)|number_format(2, '.', ',') %}
{% endfor %}

{{ totalPrice }}
```

I need to add the `totalPrice` value to itself within the loop, to out the total price of the items within the loop.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables in Twig have scopes, therefore first you need to set the variable **before**  loop:

```
{% set totalPrice = 0 %}
```

Then make the sum inside the loop:

```
{% for product in products %}

    {% set totalPrice = totalPrice + (product.quantity * product.price) %}

{% endfor %}
```

And in the and print the sum in proper format:

```
{{ totalPrice|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

[Twig's `set` documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html)